# Codeigniter page not found

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

i've website built with CODEIGNITER working perfect on my local server but when i uploaded it on live it give me error 404 and after updating .htaccess with following code now its giving me 500 error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/index.php?$1 [L]
```

any solutions...

Comment: Any reason your not using codeigniters htaccess setup? see [http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `.htaccess` rule so specify your `RewriteBase` as the manual says (you've read this of course).  That's

```
RewriteBase   /
```

for a `DOCROOT/.htaccess`  and if your Codeigniter catachall script, `index.php` is in **DOCROOT** as well then the rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

hope it help